# Puppet - Variable Precedence when applied with node

Tags: variables, puppet

In the setup I'm working the variable $var1 is declared in several places. However I'm not sure which line is last applied. The structure is as follows.

The puppet module, module1, contains a vars.pp class which is inherited by its init.pp manifest. In the vars.pp manifest var1 is declared as "value-vars".

```
#vars.pp
$var1 = "value-vars"
```

This module is applied to any node that matches a certain regex which is defined in the nodes.pp.

```
#nodes.pp
node "/nodepattern/" inherits base {
require module1
}
```

nodes.pp inherits from base.pp which declares var1 as "value-base".

```
#base.pp
$var1 = "value-base"
```

Now when the module is applied to a certain node, what value would var1 contain?

Is it "value-vars" because node block is applied before the class?

UPDATE

```
├── puppet3
│   ├──**manifests**
│   │   └───**nodes**
│   │     └──base.pp (node "base", $var1 = "value-base") 
│   ├──nodes.pp (various nodes inheriting base node, contains module1 node)
│   ├──**modules**
│   │    ├──**module1**
│   │    │    ├──**manifests**
│   │             ├──vars.pp (class "vars", $var1 = "value-vars")
│   │             ├──init.pp (class "module1", inherits vars class)
```

Comment: You could simply do `notify {"value: ${var1}":}` to show the value when testing with `puppet agent -t` or `notice("value: ${var1}")` to add the message to master's log

Comment: Thanks for idea webNeat, but this particular setup is rather a complex one, a part of a cloud management code. To execute this I need to setup a lot of systems and nodes. I was looking for the theoretical explanation on this.

Answer (score 0):

I sense some confusion here. A manifest cannot "inherit" another manifest. What's worse - from Puppet `4.0`, a manifest file will not even be able to `import` another one.

This leaves scarce options to declare globally scoped variables. You should avoid declaring the same variable globally in different `.pp` files anyway, because any compilation that imports both files will fail!

Structure that works like "if this node includes module A, use value X for variable N" is tricky with Puppet. Manifests work best if there is one central piece of information that you can rely on, e.g.

```
node <long-cloud-instance-name-here> {
    $uses_app_foo = true
    $is_master_server = false
    include my_cloud_app
}
```

Both the decision to include module A and the assignment of X to N should then be based on those node scope variables.

This pattern gets old for large numbers of nodes. It is therefor advisable to devise a [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/) hierarchy that helps you define your node data with less redundancy.

#### Update

Seeing as you *are* using classes apparently, here are the additional rules that should make things clearer:

1. a variable that is declared in the local scope (class or define body) hides variables from wider scopes that share its name
2. a variable that is declared in the node block hides a global variables with the same name

Evaluation order does not come into play. The scoping rules always apply. Multiple assignments on the same scope are forbidden and lead to a compiler error. As you are not facing that scenario, the above rules do apply.

```
$foo = 'global'

# $foo == 'global'

node default {
    $foo = 'node'
    include bar
    # $foo == 'node'
}

class bar {
    $foo = 'class'
    # $foo == 'class'
    include baz
}

class baz {
    # foo == 'node' (!)
}
```

Comment: My mistake Felix, vars.pp is a class which init.pp inherits.

As the structure appears there is not going to be a conflict created by importing both files. 

I'll have the original question updated with a diagram of the structure.

Comment: Can you make clear in your code snippets whether the variables are declared inside the respective class body? Because that is of crucial importance. - And yes, `vars.pp` is *not* a class - it's the manifest file containing class `module1::vars`. The fully qualified class names are also important.

Comment: Updated my answer with what I believe you wanted to know.